# Issue with drawing lines for most recent highest fractal and most recent lowest fractal

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I need to show a line above most recent highest fractal and a line below most recent lowest fractal. In my pine script code, the fractals plot correctly. The lines that I need start drawing correctly and draw a line above most recent highest fractal and a line below most recent lowest fractal (image 1). [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T7dG.jpg)

But after that when  a new high fractal forms  and it is not higher than the most recent highest fractal, the line draws on the new fractal. I don’t want that, I want the line for recent highest fractal to stay (image 2) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJQ85.jpg). Same if Low fractals, but images show 1 example of high fractals.

My code is given below.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Mahtab_FX
//@version=5

indicator(title="Major Fractals Test 3", shorttitle="Major Fractals Test 3", overlay=true)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Fractals Calculations and graphics


FractalCheckHighLow(fractalType) =>
    result = false
    if fractalType == "High"     // High Fractal
        result := high[4] < high[2] and high[3] <= high[2] and high[2] >= high[1] and high[2] > high[0]
    else if fractalType == "Low"   // Low Fractal
        result := low[4] > low[2] and low[3] >= low[2] and low[2] <= low[1] and low[2] < low[0]
    result


showFractals = input(true, "Show Fractals", group = "Fractals Settings")
showFractalLines = input(true, "Show fractals High / Low Lines", group = "Fractals Settings")
showFractalSweepLines = input(true, "Show fractals Sweeping Lines", group = "Fractals Settings")

//showFractalSweepBars = input(false, "Show fractals Sweep Bars", group = "Fractals Settings")

var bool enableFractalAlerts = input(false, "Enable Alerts For Fractals High / Low Sweep", group = "Fractals Settings")

var bool showHighFractals  = na
var bool showLowFractals  = na

if showFractals == true
    showHighFractals := FractalCheckHighLow("High")
    showLowFractals := FractalCheckHighLow("Low")

plotshape(showHighFractals, title='High Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, offset=-2)
plotshape(showLowFractals, title='Low Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, offset=-2)



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//drawing major fractal lines and their sweeping lines (not fully functional)

varip int majorHighFractalIndex = na
varip int majorLowFractalIndex = na

varip bool majorHighFractal = false
varip bool majorLowFractal = false

var line majorHighFractalLine = na
var line majorLowFractalLine = na




if showHighFractals
    line.delete(majorHighFractalLine)
    majorHighFractalLine := line.new(x1=bar_index-2, y1=high[2], x2=bar_index-1, y2=high[2], color=color.yellow, width=1)//, extend = extend.right)
line.set_x2(majorHighFractalLine, bar_index)
majorHighFractalIndex := bar_index - 2



if showLowFractals
    line.delete(majorLowFractalLine)
    majorLowFractalLine := line.new(x1=bar_index-2, y1=low[2], x2=bar_index-1, y2=low[2], color=color.yellow, width=1)//, extend = extend.right)
line.set_x2(majorLowFractalLine, bar_index)
majorLowFractalIndex := bar_index - 2


/////////////////////////////some logic what i want....

if showHighFractals or showLowFractals and (high < high[majorHighFractalIndex] and low > low[majorLowFractalIndex])
    majorHighFractal := true
    majorLowFractal :=true
```

I know in the script I haven’t specified it to do what I need, as I can’t figure it out. If someone can point me to how this can be achieved it will be great.

Some logic of what I want is shown below, I have tried to use it but cant figure out how and where to put it.

```
/////////////////////////////some logic what i want....

if showHighFractals or showLowFractals and (high < high[majorHighFractalIndex] and low > low[majorLowFractalIndex])
    majorHighFractal := true
    majorLowFractal :=true
```